# Override a función built-in

Tags: javascript, override, survey

Cómo puedo hacer override a una función que no está visible en el objeto? Cuando busco la función en la instancia del objeto no me aparece.

```js
import { Model } from "survey-core";

const survey = new Model(QuizItems);

survey.getDisplayClockTime();
```

Aquí se puede ver la definición:

```js
    SurveyModel.prototype.getDisplayClockTime = function (val) {
        var min = Math.floor(val / 60);
        var sec = val % 60;
        var secStr = sec.toString();
        if (sec < 10) {
            secStr = "0" + secStr;
        }
        return "".concat(min, ":").concat(secStr);
    };
```

Este es el componente que estoy usando: [SurveyJS](https://surveyjs.io/)

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Flavio, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes y agregues tu código como texto, de esa forma recibirás ayuda en vez de votos negativos. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Hola @MarcePuente, así está bien? Primera vez que posteo una pregunta en esta web.

Comment: Flavio, nadie podría hacerlo mejor!!